# Generating a spherical shape given radius and number of faces

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I am completely lost on this one -- I can't find any similar question on the net. Given the radius of an unknown spherical object, and the number of faces (minimum of 6), how would I get the size and 3D offset (position and rotation) (origin at 0,0,0) of each of those?

In this case, Y is the vertical axis and the Z axis represents depth, with -1 being forward and 1 being backward.

Programming this in Lua, but any other language / pseudo-code is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you have not searched properly

- there are quite a few of related Q&A even here on SO/SE
- for example here are some of mine
- [equidistant points on  sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031737/2521214)
- [sphere surface area mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082674/2521214)
- these links can help to get your problem started (if not solve completely).

You did not provide enough information

- so I am assuming that you want to construct sphere from the same shape/sized polygons

I would start like this:

1. find equidistant points

   - these will be the vertexes
   - how to do it is explained in the first link
2. make connections to form the faces

   - just loop between layers and connect the points as you need
   - an example of rectangular grid/faces is in the second link

The main problem is that

- if your faces are the same shape/size (not triangles)
- then you can not use any number of faces but only some are valid
- the lower limit is not enough